# Binding the scope with side menu does not work - ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, ionic-framework

I want to show 2 different ion-list on the Menu according to a user "role" in my App.

**app.js**

```
  .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    cache: false,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })
```

**AppCtrl**

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  // EXAMPLE
  $scope.user = {
    name: "example",
    role: "client"
  };
})
```

**menu.html**

```
     <ion-list ng-if="user.role == 'manager' ">
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/search">
          MANAGER
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/songbook">
           ITEM A
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>

      <ion-list ng-if="user.role == 'client' ">
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/search">
          CLIENT
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/search">
          ITEM B
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
```

And the issue is that it does not render any ion-list ! is just empty!

It seems to me that angular is not binding the "scope.user"
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting any console error?

Comment: No, even if I do a "console.log("Something");" from the AppCtrl it doesn't show !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your controller' range contains your post html code?

```
 <ion-list ng-if="user.role == 'manager' ">
```

If the controller includes your list code,

then do you try to avoid array first , like

`$scope.user_role == 'manager'` in the controller,

`ng-if="user.role == 'manager'` in the html.

As far as I know ,if you insert a xxx.html into a large controller, using the array like you is correct(if not ,data can bot be reached into the inserted html file)

Anyway. Did you try whether it functions well when you avoid the array, if not, the reason must be the range of angularjs does not reach your post html code

Comment: It seems like angular does not reach my html code. But just for this controller, maybe because is "abstract" ?
Because I have others controllers (not abstract) that works!

Comment: @IsmaHaro, "abstract" listen like something untrustworthy, ^.^ Last year I came across many problems in angularjs when I just started learning it. I did not figure out some of them due to the tight time. However, if you have succeed in some cases,  maybe you can compare them or rewrite the code above. Hope you succeed!